# How to get Elasticsearch score result detail?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an elastic index that keeps some items. The structure is below.

```
public class items
{
    public string item_no { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public int campaign { get; set; }
    public int in_stock { get; set; }
    // Next properties only include [a-z0-9]. Not any other characters
    public string score_item_no { get; set; }   
    public string score_group_one { get; set; }
    public string score_group_two { get; set; }
    public string score_description { get; set; }
    public string score_all_fields { get; set; } /* score_item_no + score_group_one + score_group_two + score_description and something else */
}

public class ClassForScore
{
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string item_no { get; set; }
}
```

I must filter useless records from the result. I've decided to use the score option and made a function to calculate the average score. So first I call the elasticsearch for scores, and then I call with minscore parameter. I could not find any solution for filtering useless resultsAny advice for this? This is question one.

And the second one:
The first score call returns 7 records. Every record has different scores. For example, the first record has 1100 scores.
But I would like to know where this 1100 comes from?
1000 from score_item_no and 100 from score_group_one, or 500 from score_group_one matching 5 parts and 500 of them score_group_two match 5 parts and 100 from score_description matching 2 parts.
Is there a way to find score detail?

```
    QueryContainer queryContainsAnd = new WildcardQuery() { Field = "score_all_fields", Value = "*" + mykeyword + "*" };
    QueryContainer queryEqualsOr =  new TermQuery() { Field = "category", Value = *something1* };
    queryEqualsOr |=  new TermQuery() { Field = "category", Value = *something2* };
    QueryContainer queryEqualsAnd = new TermQuery() { Field = "campaign", Value = 1 };
    queryEqualsAnd &= new TermQuery() { Field = "in_stock", Value = 1 };
            
            
    QueryContainer mainQuery = queryContainsAnd & queryEqualsAnd & queryEqualsOr;
    
    Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<ClassForScore>, QueryContainer> fo = funcScoreParam(new ClassForScore(), filterItemNo, filterGroupOne, filterGroupTwo, filterDescription, mainQuery);
    ISearchResponse<ClassForScore> srcSkor = elasticClient.Search<ClassForScore>(s => s
        .RequestConfiguration(r => r.DisableDirectStreaming())
        .Query(fo)
        .Size(100)
    );
    IReadOnlyCollection<IHit<ClassForScore>> lstSkor = srcSkor.Hits;
    double? dblSkorAvg = 0;
    // Some calculation..
    //.....
    Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<items>, QueryContainer> fo2 = funcScoreParam(new ClassForScore(), filterItemNo, filterGroupOne, filterGroupTwo, filterDescription, mainQuery);
    ISearchResponse<items> srcResult = elasticClient.Search<items>(s => s
        .RequestConfiguration(r => r.DisableDirectStreaming())
        .From(0)
        .Size(100)
        .Sort(S => S.Descending(SortSpecialField.Score).Ascending(r => r.item_no))
        .MinScore(dblSkorAvg)
        .Query(fo2)
    );
    
    
    private Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<T>, QueryContainer> funcScoreParam<T>(T nesne, QueryContainer filterItemNo, QueryContainer filterGroupOne, QueryContainer filterGroupTwo, QueryContainer filterDescription, QueryContainer mainQuery) where T : class
    {
        return new Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<T>, QueryContainer>(q => q
            .FunctionScore(fsc => fsc
                .BoostMode(FunctionBoostMode.Sum)
                .ScoreMode(FunctionScoreMode.Sum)
                .Functions(fu => fu
                        .Weight(w => w
                            .Weight(1000)
                            .Filter(wf => wf
                            .Bool(bb => bb
                            .Must(filterItemNo))
                            ))
                        .Weight(w => w
                            .Weight(100)
                            .Filter(wf => wf
                            .Bool(bb => bb
                            .Must(filterGroupOne))
                            ))
                        .Weight(w => w
                            .Weight(100)
                            .Filter(wf => wf
                            .Bool(bb => bb
                            .Must(filterGroupTwo)) 
                            ))
                        .Weight(w => w
                            .Weight(50)
                            .Filter(wf => wf
                            .Bool(bb => bb
                            .Must(filterDescription))
                            ))
                    )
                    .Query(q2 => q2
                        .Bool(b => b
                        .Should(mainQuery))
                    )
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `explain` parameter on the search API to return detailed information about score computation for each hit

```cs
ISearchResponse<items> srcResult = elasticClient.Search<items>(s => s
    .RequestConfiguration(r => r.DisableDirectStreaming())
    .From(0)
    .Size(100)
    .Sort(S => S.Descending(SortSpecialField.Score).Ascending(r => r.item_no))
    .MinScore(dblSkorAvg)
    .Query(fo2)
    .Explain() // <-- explain score computation for each hit
);
```

There is also a dedicated [explain API to understand how a specific document's score is calculated.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot @RussCam. And I found that if you send null QueryContainer to the function as parameter, total score includes that by it's weight. BTW going to elasticsearch twice is the right way to calculate score and filtering or any advice for that?

Comment: > BTW going to elasticsearch twice is the right way to calculate score and filtering or any advice for that?
I'm not sure why you're doing that, but Elasticsearch will calculate a score for each document for a given query. Scoring is calculated with [BM25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25), and so scores are relative to the frequency of terms in query input within documents and the inverse frequency across documents. Looking at your query, it looks like using boosting on queries in a `bool` query, rather than weights on queries in functions might be what you want.

Comment: How Elasticsearch calculates the score without field's weight? Maybe, there is a problem in my structure. I have 5 fields for scoring and one field for searching including all keywords of each documents. I'm calculating scores according to which scoring field contains the keyword. I'm not sure if I could explain correctly with my English. In this case what do you advice?

Comment: I have asked it as a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63670605/elasticsearch-filter-by-score

Answer (score 0):

In the Python `elasticsearch_dsl` library the syntax for this is

```
 my_search.extra(explain=True).execute()
```